# when i hide extension my get and post method are not working?

Tags: .htaccess, post, get

I write code in .htaccess file to hide extension but my form get and post method doesn't work so
I added

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST [NC]
```

code to file then post method works but still not get method.

if I add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !GET [NC]
```

then it works but again my extension get shown. Kindly do help here.

Comment: Thanks for adding your efforts in your question, keep it up. Please do add samples/examples of urls which you want to rewrite/redirect in your question for better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: _“I write code in .htaccess file to hide extension”_ - and where is that code? If this is what you have a problem with, then your question should contain that first of all, don’t you think? We can not _guess_ what you did to achieve that.